# How to define my own continuous wavelet by using Python?

Tags: python, scipy, wavelet, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

As the title shows, I want to define my own continuous wavelet by Python. However, I don't know how to achieve this exactly.

The formula of my wavelet mother function is below

[image]

It looks something like the Mexican hat wavelet, but they are different.

So how can I define such a custom wavelet by Python, then CWT can be performed using this wavelet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html) you need a function that takes a number of points and a scale to provide as a `wavelet` argument

So we define it as such:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mother_wavelet = lambda z : np.exp(-z*z/4)*(2-z*z)/(4*math.sqrt(math.pi))

def mexican_hat_like(n,scale):
    x = np.linspace(-n/2,n/2,n)
    return mother_wavelet(x/scale)
```

Let's test it. We note that in fact something that looks very similar to yours is [available](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.ricker.html#scipy.signal.ricker). The difference is in scaling `a` and also the constant is front looks slightly different. Note `math.sqrt(2)` scaling for the Ricker wavelet

```
points = 100
a = 4.0
vec_ours = mexican_hat_like(points, a)
vec_theirs = signal.ricker(points, a*math.sqrt(2))
plt.plot(vec_ours, label = 'ours')
plt.plot(vec_theirs, label = 'ricker')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

Here is the graph:

[image: wavelets]

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer! Why not define ```mother_wavelet``` inside the function ```mexican_hat_like```?

Comment: no reason -- can go there if you do not need it elsewhere

Comment: I noticed that the x-coordinate of your plot is not the true value of the wavelet's coordinate. Is there a way to show the true x values in the wavelet plot?

Comment: you can see them in the definition of the wavelet `x = np.linspace(-n/2,n/2,n)
    return mother_wavelet(x/scale)` so not sure what you mean? I am not sure what are the 'true' values of wavelets but you can change your x-s there